# Get values from another a column based on a condition using loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is the dataframe I have I need to get the following:

```
 empid    role
   123    lead
   124    lead
   125 manager
   156    lead
   129 manager
```

while iterating over each value of a column role I need to get the value of empid if role == lead and store it in another variable

Answer (score 1):

Use `.loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[df['role'] == 'lead', 'empid']
0    123
1    124
3    156
Name: empid, dtype: int64
```

If you want a list:

```
empid = df.loc[df['role'] == 'lead', 'empid'].tolist()
```

```
>>> empid
[123, 124, 156]
```

Read the documentation [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)